# Pipe is not working in angular2

Tags: angular

I added below line in my component code

```
 pipes: [ OrderByPipe ].
```

It showing following error

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; pipes:
>   typeof OrderByPipe[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Component'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
>   'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'.

How to solve this

Answer (score 2):

`pipes` in `@Component()` is the old way and not supported anymore

Add the pipe to

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [OrderByPipe],
  ...
})
```